# Need a gap query to check for gap in daily price data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data for 2 Securities as illustration, there are 2 tables where i want to check gaps

Price Table --- Time Series Format only Weekdays data

```
Sec ID    Date       Price
1       01-Jan-2014  10
1       02-Jan-2014  --- gap in price record not exist in price table
1       03-Jan-2014  --- gap in price record not exist in price table
1       04-Jan-2014  Saturday 
1       05-Jan-2014  Sunday
1       06-Jan-2014  --- gap in price record not exist in price table
1       07-Jan-2014  11
```

Output Needed gap in Price from 02-Jan till 06-Jan-2014

Shares Table --- Data stored in HOC Format

```
Sec ID      Start        End          Shares
1          01-Jan-2013  31-Dec-2013    100
1          07-Jan-2014  31-Jan-2014    105
```

Output needed gap in shares from 01-Jan-2014 till 06-Jan-2014 (weekend should be included)

I have calendar Table available with me which has all weekdays and excluded weekend

Please advise for efficent query

Thanks
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your question in bad way, but I'll try to guess what you need.

so I created dummy table this way:

```
  create table nk_first_one(
  sec_id NUMBER,
  price_date date,
  price VARCHAR2(50)
  );

  insert into nk_first_one values(1, '01-Jan-2014', '10');
  insert into nk_first_one values(1, '04-Jan-2014', 'Saturday');
  insert into nk_first_one values(1, '05-Jan-2014', 'Sunday');
  insert into nk_first_one values(1, '07-Jan-2014', '11');
```

And here is simple query which counts each missing day for every row in table:

```
  select sec_id, 
  price_date, 
  lag(PRICE_DATE, 1, PRICE_DATE) over(order by PRICE_DATE) prevoius_price_date,
  (price_date - lag(PRICE_DATE, 1, PRICE_DATE) over(order by PRICE_DATE)) price_days_gap
  from nk_first_one;
```

Here is result of that query:

```
      SEC_ID PRICE_DATE PREVOIUS_PRICE_DATE PRICE_DAYS_GAP
  ---------- ---------- ------------------- --------------
           1 01-JAN-14  01-JAN-14                        0 
           1 04-JAN-14  01-JAN-14                        3 
           1 05-JAN-14  04-JAN-14                        1 
           1 07-JAN-14  05-JAN-14                        2
```

So for each row you have number of days from previous price assigned (and as far as I understand you need those with PRICE_DAYS_GAP > 1).

Is that what you wanted? 
For the second query you can go the same way. Oracle analytic functions are easy to understand :)

Comment: Not Helpful...I need a query which gives me gap date (not gap days count)...so my final output should be Gap Start '02-Jan-2014' and Gap End '06-Jan-2014'

Comment: are you serious? So you are too lazy to just add one similar line to the query...

Comment: You have PREVIOUS_PRICE_DATE and it is your gap start date if PRICE_DAYS_GAP > 1 ... If you don't understand it - I don't know what to say....